# yolo v8 result grap

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

Below is a graph of the results of running yolo v8. I would like to know the meaning of the horizontal axis, vertical axis, and units in the following graph. The code used is the following code, which is the yolo v8 code as is without any customization.
https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics
I would also like to know the meaning of "box_loss", "cls_loss" and "dfl_loss".

I understood from my research that the horizontal axis of the graph is the number of epochs. However, I did not know about the vertical axis as far as I could find out.

[image: Result Graph]

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the horizontal axis of the graph is typically the number of epochs. An epoch is a complete iteration of the training dataset through the neural network during training. More epochs generally lead to better training of the model but can also lead to overfitting if done excessively.

The vertical axis in a typical YOLO (You Only Look Once) training graph would represent the loss value. Loss is a measure of how well the model is performing during training. Lower loss values indicate better model performance, while higher values indicate worse performance. The goal during training is to minimize the loss value.

In the context of YOLOv8, you mentioned "box_loss", "cls_loss", and "dfl_loss". These are components of the overall loss value:

"box_loss": This is the bounding box regression loss, which measures the error in the predicted bounding box coordinates and dimensions compared to the ground truth. A lower box_loss means that the predicted bounding boxes are more accurate.

"cls_loss": This is the classification loss, which measures the error in the predicted class probabilities for each object in the image compared to the ground truth. A lower cls_loss means that the model is more accurately predicting the class of the objects.

"dfl_loss": This is the deformable convolution layer loss, a new addition to the YOLO architecture in YOLOv8. This loss measures the error in the deformable convolution layers, which are designed to improve the model's ability to detect objects with various scales and aspect ratios. A lower dfl_loss indicates that the model is better at handling object deformations and variations in appearance.

The overall loss value is typically a weighted sum of these individual losses. The specific units of the vertical axis would be dependent on the implementation, but generally, they represent the magnitude of the error or the difference between the predicted and ground truth values.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you can interpret losses this way :

***cls_loss***
It is the Classification Loss. When it's high, it means basically that you have low value of confidence on the class you should predict. You can imagine it as the -log of the probability that you predicted for the class that should be predicted.

If the probability is close to 1, the -log is close to 0.
If the probability is close to 0 (for example 0.1), the -log is close to 1.

You sum it all and it makes your loss.

***bbox_loss*** 
It is representing the difference between the intersection over union of groundtruth and prediction and 1.

If the prediction was perfectly matching the groudtruth, the ratio between the intersection of it's bbox and the union would be close to 1.
[image]

But it's a little more complicate than that.... if you look at the first case, whatever the distance between the box and the prediction, the IoU is 0 and the Loss is one.
That's why in this paper :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.08287.pdf

They proposed dIoU and cIoU (this one i guess is use in Yolov8).

[image]

To simplify, you can imagine the loss value as *Loss = 1 - IoU +d²/c²*.
It means when the IoU is 0, we add an information to help the model to first make bboxes closer before fitting.

**dfl_loss**
DFL loss means Distributed focal Loss, and it's coming from here :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.04388.pdf

Instead of predicting directly the bboxes coordinates, we predict a distribution.
It's because labelling can contains ambiguity and errors.

Because we predict a distribution, we are able to compute the final bboxes coordinates values with some kind of integration :

[image]

[image]

The more the DFL Loss is high, the more the histogram will be flattenned, the less high will be the values bounding y.

If you want more information, i suggest you to read yolov8 paper :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.09972.pdf